# Windows 8.1 app not listed in Windows 10 store?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10

I have a Windows store app (made for Windows 8.1). After upgrading to Windows 10, I was able to install my app without problems.

I was always able to find my app through the category and the top charts. But now, I cannot find it at all. Only when I search for a keyword related to the app, it shows up as expected.

Is that normal? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft regarding this matter and received a reply.

It appears that Microsoft has changed the chart listing algorithm in Windows 10, kicking all apps out (from Windows 8/8.1) that are not cross-platform pc-mobile. You can still find the applications by the search, but they are not visible in any charts anymore.